# Show emberjs computed property in view

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

**I am having trouble displaying computed properties in my view**

I am learning EmberJS for less than a week. Different tutorials have different coding styles, which is very confusing, so I am following http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/07/an-in-depth-introduction-to-ember-js/ 
I saw some similar posts on stackoverflow but the code is too complex for me to understand, and my question is very basic and no post I have seen just answers that bare basic.

**Here is my 'users' handlebars template.** It is written in index.html. I am putting only the handlebars script part.

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="users">
    <div>

    <ul class="users-listing">
        {{#each user in controller}}
            <li>{{user.name}} ..... {{user.id}} ..... {{user.NameWithId}}</li>
        {{else}}
            <li>no users… :-(</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

    Total users: {{usersCount}}

    </div>


</script>
```

**Here is my model**

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter;

App.User = DS.Model.extend({
  name         : DS.attr(),
  email        : DS.attr(),
  bio          : DS.attr(),
  avatarUrl    : DS.attr(),
  creationDate : DS.attr()
});
```

**Here is my Controller**

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['id'],
  sortAscending: true, // false = descending

  usersCount: function(){
    return this.get('model.length');
  }.property('@each'),

  NameWithId: function() {
    return this.get('id') + ' -> ' + this.get('name');
  }.property('id', 'name')
});
```

After executing the script, I can see ID and name, but in the place of NameWithId I get **just blank**
Even my web console in Firefox shows **nothing**

In my template I changed

```
user.NameWithId
```

to

```
user.get('NameWithId')
```

Now I get Parse Error: Expecting 'ID', got 'INVALID'

Using:
jQuery 1.10.2
handlebars 1.0.0
Ember 1.0.0
EmberData 1.0.0-beta3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The computed property should be on the model, not the controller. It's a property of a single user instance, whereas your controller is an ArrayController, for many user instances (hence the `@each` in the previous computed property declaration).

Answer (score 3):

You can place it on the model like sevenseacat said, or you can use an itemController which will wrap up each item in the array with a controller, and that's where you would place this property.

```
App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
   itemController: 'user'
})

App.UserController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  NameWithId: function() {
    return this.get('id') + ' -> ' + this.get('name');
  }.property('id', 'name')
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much for helping a newbie! And thanks for the code too!